# Subtract total of one query from another query

Tags: php, mysql

I thought I had this answered from a previous post, but I still can't get this right.  I'll try this another way and simplify it:

```
Query 1:
SELECT SUM((TA.task_average*TC.completed)/60) AS manual

Query 2:
SUM(M.minutes/60) AS automatic
```

I need to subtract query 2 from 1.  I would like to combine it if possible and avoid multiple queries.  I have all of my joins and groupings how I need them it's this piece I am having a heck of a time with.

Edited with final (included rounding to two decimal places):

```
ROUND((SUM((TA.task_average*TC.completed)/60) - SUM(M.minutes/60)),2) AS diff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just subtract them like this:

```
SELECT (SUM((TA.task_average*TC.completed)/60) - SUM(M.minutes/60)) AS Difference FROM ...
```

Comment: Wow, I thought I tried that, but apparently not!  Worked exactly how I needed.  I just added in ROUND to get them down to 2 decimal places and I was golden.  Thanks!